# Schema.org + Laravel = way too complicated?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, schema

I recently completed my first Laravel project (I really liked the look of the framework and wanted to give it a try) and was reflecting on what I think I did well, what I did poorly, and what I want to do differently next time.

One of the biggest issues I noticed I had was that in a gross effort to avoid duplication of data I had some pretty hideous work to do in order to extract meaningful information from my database.

At the outset of the project I used [schema.org](http://schema.org/) as a rough basis for designing my models. For instance, when I wanted to store `Employee`s and `Customer`s:

- Create a `Person` model
- A `Person` hasMany `Role`s
- A `Customer` **is a** (morphs) `Role`
- An `Employee` **is a** (morphs) `Role`
- An `Organization` hasMany `Employee`s
- An `Organization` hasMany `Customer`s

At first this seems nice, because a person can be **both** an employee **and** a customer (you can shop at WalMart and work for WalMart). Also since a person can have many roles, they can be multiple customers and multiple employees -- if they shop at more than one store or if they have two jobs.

However I ran into issues when I wanted to do something like "find all employees for organization X whose name is John":

```
$employees = $organization->employees;
$employeesNamedJohn = new Collection();
foreach( $employees as $employee ) {
    if( $employee->role->person->name == 'John' )
        $employeesNamedJohn->add( $employee );
}
```

This seems awfully complicated (not to mention inefficient), especially considering if I hadn't invented the messed up schema it would just be a one-liner:

```
$employees = $organization->employees()->where('name', 'John')->get();
```

So am I just doing something wrong? Does Laravel have a simple way to handle complex relationships like this, or is the answer to simply never let your relationships get this complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) on your models could really help:

```php
class Role extends Model
{
    public function scopeNamed($query, $name)
    {
        $query->whereHas('person', function ($query) use ($name) {
            $query->where('name', $name);
        });
    }
}

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function scopeNamed($query, $name)
    {
        $query->whereHas('role', function ($query) use ($name) {
            $query->named($name);
        });
    }
}
```

Then you could do this:

```php
$employees = $organization->employees()->named('John')->get();
```

Much better.

Answer (score 0):

As an extra,

I did implement Josheph Silber his answer in
https://github.com/noud/seo

Look at the Entity-Relationship Diagram below in the readme.md
Entity role having fields

- roleable_id (the id to where the foreign key points)
- roleable_type (the entity the foreign key points to)

In Laravel this is

- [Role model](https://github.com/noud/seo/blob/master/app/Models/Role.php)
- [trait for Employee, Customer, ...](https://github.com/noud/seo/blob/master/app/Models/Traits/Role.php)
- [so you can fetch Employees named $name](https://github.com/noud/seo/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/OrganizationController.php)